# Scala: Converting a Double from Scientific Notation without losing precision?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, format, double

I'd like to convert a double such as `1.1231053E7` to `11,231,053.0` in scala. Currently the way I am converting doubles is to do this `f"$number"` where `number` is a double value. Unfortunately this just gives me a string with `1.1231053E7`.

I can convert it out of scientific notation using `NumberFormat` or `DecimalFormat` but these also force me to choose a predetermined precision. I want flexible precision. So...

```
val number1 = 1.2313215
val number2 = 100
val number4 = 3.333E2
```

... when converted should be...

```
1.2313215
100
333.3
```

Currently `DecimalFormat` makes me choose the precision during construction like so: `new DecimalFormat(##.##)`. Each `#` after `.` signifies a decimal point.

If I use `f"$number"`, it treats the decimal points correctly but, like I said before, it is unable to handle the scientific notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decide how many places after the `.` you need, write out the number hiding the zeros:

```
val fmt = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.##############")
for (x <- List[Double](1.2313215, 100, 3.333E2)) println(fmt.format(x))
```

prints:

```
1.2313215
100
333.3
```